# How should I best name my timestamp fields?

Tags: naming-convention

When I am looking to create some timestamp fields (or other date/time style fields), what is the best way to name them? Should I just put record_timestamp?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

You should describe the purpose of the column and not necessarily the data type.  You can include date/time/timestamp in the name, but you should also include the meaning.  For example

- CreationDate
- StartDate
- StatusTime
- Accessed
- Updated

Adding Date/Time/Timestamp and such at the end is particularly useful when the abscence of the addition would conflict with another column.  For example, a table may need both a Status and a StatusTime.

Comment: Just to add my two cents. I worked with many legacy MRP systems and found CreatedOnUtc and UpdatedOnUtc used often.

Comment: I think "Accessed" and "Updated" can be ambiguous, since it can also imply boolean (at least in Ruby world)

Comment: @GeovaniMartinez that can be confusing, as a lot of SQL databases, PostgreSQL included, store at UTC and read in client's timezone.

Comment: And if the time unit is supposed to be UTC vs System Local then specify _UTC in the column name.  Thank you from all of us who must maintain the code later.

Comment: Accessed and Updated could be ambiguous with WHO accessed or updated, which is a fairly common thing to track

Comment: Accessed and Updated should not be ambiguous given the datatype.  It would also be clear from the other field being named AccessedBy or UpdatedBy, however, it would certainly make it abundantly clear to include Date in the name for the Date/Time fields.

Answer (score 44):

How about `xyz_at` for a `timestamp` and `xyz_on` for a `date` field - eg `start_at` or `start_on`?

Normally I'd avoid including the data type in the field name - much better if you can infer what you need to know about the type from the name of any field (a field called `description` is unlikely to be an `integer`) - but being able to tell the difference between a `timestamp` and a `date` is often helpful.

Answer (score 32):

I use:

- created_at
- updated_at

Comment: "at" can imply location too.  What about "when" instead of "at"?

Comment: "at" or "as at" is used frequently in legal and financial documents to refer to when something happened. http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/112770/understanding-as-of-as-at-and-as-from

Comment: It can still be ambiguous. What if you need to know the time and location at which is was updated? `updated_at` could be either. But I think the answer is, as always with naming, use the most concise name that removes all realistic ambiguity. I.e. if in a particular context there is potential for a certain confusion, eliminate it, but don't use names that are more verbose than is required for that

Comment: how about "on". Although it implies a date more than a time, it's still pretty obvious

Comment: Update location is much less frequently stored in software than when something was updated, so it doesn't make sense to give it too much weight. Because it's used much less often, then something more verbose like `update_location`, `update_location_id` would be acceptable.

Answer (score 8):

I found that using column names such as `create_time`, `update_time` and `expire_time` leads to better readability when it comes to method naming and specs (RSpec).

Answer (score 5):

I looked at your profile and it says you work with SQL Server and in SQL Server TIMESTAMP data type has nothing to do with date or time and its used to kind of version stamping the rows. This is very useful in identifying which rows have been modified from a given point of time.

If you use TIMESTAMP then you don't have to specify a column name and SQL Server will create a column "TimeStamp" for you. But it is recommended to use "ROWVERSION" data type and in this case you have to specify the column name.

What's the best name for a column like this? It depends, and I would use something like VersionStamp, RV etc... What I consider important is NOT how you name it but are you using that consistently across the board.

HTH

Ref: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182776(v=sql.90).aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182776.aspx

Answer (score 5):

There is no exact right way to do it, only important thing is to be consistent across your code base and databases so developers are not confused.

Exact naming depends on the language conventions but I would choose one of the following below:

```
Python, Java, ORACLE/Postgresql

created_at, createdAt, CREATED_AT // Time when the record was created
updated_at, updatedAt, UPDATED_AT // Time when the record was last modified
started_at, startedAt, STARTED_AT // Some other record time

Or

create_time, createTime, CREATE_TIME
update_time, updateTime, UPDATE_TIME
start_time, startTime, START_TIME
```

Pretty much all fields are stored as timestamp, there will some fields required as date but usually they are more related to the business domain and could be named as per coming request

- birthday
- realase_date
- business_day

All timestamp fields to be stored in UTC.

Answer (score 3):

**I prefer using conventions that already exist.**

Unix and programming languages have a widely accepted convention of `mtime` for *Modification Time*

For creation time,

- BSD and Windows use birthtime
- Windows also uses Creation Time
- xstat uses `btime`
- ext4 uses `crtime`
- JFS and btrfs use `otime` (don't ask, guessing "origination").

**So for me, I pick `mtime`, and `crtime` for meta data.**

For user supplied data, I go with what the field represents. If it's a birthday, I just say `user_birthday`.

As far as precision, for some it seems to hang them up on too much precision. You can store your `birthdate` as a timestamp (after all you were technically birthed at a time of day), but the SQL spec has casts from higher-precision to lower precision so if you're using a decent database this shouldn't be an issue. In your app itself, you can always truncate when needed. That is to say, I would never go `birthday_date`.

Comment: This convention is terrible. You cannot figure out on your own what such variables mean. You need to know what the "m" or "cr" stand for. I really hate pretty much all unix conventions and magic abbreviations for absolutely everything and anything: etc, usr, cpy, md, rd, mtime, btime... gosh who came up with it? :-|

Comment: occurrence time

Answer (score 2):

I prefer to use a prefix of DT for date stamps. For example: DTOpened, DTClosed, DTLastAccessed. This lets me list out all the DTxxxx for a quick reference of all date stamps in a given table.

Answer (score 2):

I work for Texas Instruments, and on their systems they use xxxx_**dttm**

Answer (score 2):

In order to maintain consistency accross column names, I would suggest you to the following syntax:

```
dateCreated
dateUpdated
dateAccessed
dateStarted
date...
```

Answer (score 2):

As suggest by @Evan Carroll, go with the existing standards unless you have strong reason to break the pattern.

If this is something new then you can follow any answer which best suits you.

I use *_on and *_by because it helps me to keep it consistent for when and who of the row:

```
- created_on & created_by
- updated_on & updated_by
- deleted_on & deleted_by -- soft delete
- approved_on & approved_by
```

Answer (score 1):

I would used a meaningful prefix and _TSMP as a suffix e.g. CREATION_TSMP or LAST_UPDATE_TSMP

Answer (score 1):

For timestamps:

e.g. 2022-09-12T00:00:00Z

- updated_at
- created_at

It's concise and if used as a standard there's not confusion.

---

For dates:

e.g. 2022-09-12

- updated_on
- created_on

The same comment from timestamps. It's concise and when used as a standard it's not confusing.

---

For times without dates which is generally used for scheduling more than recording a time something occurred as that would be a timestamp:

e.g. 12:30:00

- send_time
- run_time

Since this is not used nearly as frequently in my experience as `at` and `on` using `time` is sufficient, plus it's short enough.

---

There was a comment about `_at` being used for locations. While I can understand that I haven't worked at a business where locations of events was needed. For something like user's ip information we would just have something `ip_country`, `ip_city`, etc. For other types of locations we would use `location_id`. If you need locations and `_at` is confusing then by all means use a different standard.

I personally care more about consistency and having a standard than a particular standard, as long as there's backing for that standard and not something made up randomly.